# Missing search hit for "circled r"

Tags: bug, search

Why does a [Q&A search for "circled r"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22circled+r%22) show only [reirab’s answer about private airports](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/18981/2143) and not [PMoubed’s question about the Communications section in the Chart Supplement](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23772/2143)? Both contain the phrase in question.

Comment: [Seems to be a known issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260131/257476)

Comment: @fooot Even curiouser: [search for \*circled r\*](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=*circled+r*) and get the complement, PMoubed's question but not reirab's answer. PMoubed used `Circled R` formatted as code, which appears to confuse the SE site search.

Comment: Obviously, it's because my answer is better. :) Or it could just be because SE's search is awful. One of those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: Because the site's built-in search sucks.

Longer answer: Stack Exchange sites are Q&A platforms, not search engines. The built-in search is kind of a best-effort thing: Sometimes it's good, other times it misses things or pulls up irrelevant pages.
[Use Google if comprehensive results are important](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22circled+R%22+site:aviation.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Searching Google for '"circled r" chart supplement" leads to the [airport tag](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport) with a promising looking excerpt, but by the time you visit the link, the question isn't in the page content. Yes, searching Google for '"circled r" afd' happens to yield the desired hit, and, yes, AF/D with chart supplement is an odd synonym. Still, it's a frustrating user experience.

Comment: @GregBacon Note the specific search construct I used in that link (`"circled R" site:aviation.stackexchange.com"`) - theres a reason I constructed the query that way (first result: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23772/what-does-mean-in-a-fd)

Comment: (not that it isn't a subpar user experience either way, but search being lousy has been a network-wide complaint for quite a while: I doubt we're going to get a fix for it, search is a hard problem)

Comment: Has a Google custom search box been considered?